# notifyDataSetChanged(); not refreshing

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to refresh my list view everytime i press the search button with the string from the edit text but the list is not refreshing.

this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private DataSource datasource;

    Button search;
    EditText searchEt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearch);

        searchEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTextSearch);

        search.setOnClickListener(this);

        datasource = new DataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Recipe> values = datasource.getAllRecipe(Recipe.l);
        // List<Recipe> values = datasource.getAllRecipe();

        // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Recipe> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Recipe>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<Recipe> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Recipe>) getListAdapter();
        Recipe title = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bSearch:
            try {
                String s = searchEt.getText().toString();
                Recipe.l = s;
                Log.i("1", Recipe.l + "");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Row Empty or ID not found");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            break;

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

this is the methods from my DAO:

```
public List<Recipe> getAllRecipe(String l) throws SQLException {
        List<Recipe> titles = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(Helper.TABLE_RECIPES, allColumns,
                Helper.COLUMN_TAG + "='" + Recipe.l + "'", null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Recipe title = cursorToRecipe(cursor);
            titles.add(title);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();

        return titles;
    }

    private Recipe cursorToRecipe(Cursor cursor) {
        Recipe title = new Recipe();
        title.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        title.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        return title;
    }
```

and this is from my model class:

```
public static String l = "chicken";
```

my onclicklisteners are working, buttons are working.. i've checked the log in the DDMS and the variable l is changing.. the only problem is the listview not refreshing.

Comment: You dont use in setListAdapter() in OnClick(). becuase you dont ust the same adapter that you use in OnCreate() ,hte call to notifyDataSetChanged() is on empty adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting class cast exception because you're typecasting getAllRecipe() (which returns a list of Recipe objects) to a Recipe object (which is not a list of Recipe objects). Try changing it to

```
title = (List<Recipe>) datasource.getAllRecipe(Recipe.l);
```

There's a better approach to what you're trying to achive but this should keep you going. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` is not refreshing because you are not modifying the contents array of the `ArrayAdapter` anywhere in your code in the `onClick` method. Therefore, when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, it uses the same old array and shows the same previous contents. 
Hence no change.

Try setting a new array to the adapter in `onClick` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` again. That should solve your problem. :)

Comment: i did try this: title = (Recipe) datasource.getAllRecipe(Recipe.l);
    adapter.add(title);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

but its returning a class cast exception...

Comment: most probably because getAllRecipes gives you a list whereas addapter.add expects a single Recipe. did you try it with addAll?